# Verilog for Shift Register

Tags: verilog, shift-register

Would like seek for help on the following Verilog Shift Register Code. The following code was given to me and my task is to convert that into a schematic form.

```
module shift_register(
  output reg [9:0] out_q,
  input clk,
  input reset,
  input test,
  input in_cg,
  input in_sr);

always @(posedge clk or negedge reset) begin
  if (reset ==0) begin
    out_q <= 10'd0;
    end
  else if (test == 0) begin
    out_q <= {out_q[8:0], in_cg};
  end
  else begin
    out_q<={out_q[8:0],in_sr};
  end
end //end always

endmodule  //endmodule
```

I had draft my schematic as attached as [ShiftRegister](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeE76.jpg) here. Someone please help to verify is this the right schematic manually "synthesize" from the Verilog RTL code? Thanks.

Comment: That seems correct to me

Comment: You can definately verify it using a simulator like Logisim.

Answer (score -1):

You should replace
"end else if" to "end else begin if"

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge reset) begin
    if (reset ==0) begin
        out_q <= 10'd0;
    end else begin
        if (test == 0) begin
            out_q <= {out_q[8:0], in_cg};
        end else begin
            out_q<={out_q[8:0],in_sr};
        end
    end
end //end always
```